# Link shared library through makefile

Tags: c, makefile, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

The code compiles as it should, but somehow, the binary file doesn't know where the library is.

```
❯ ldd myteams_cli 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcbc1b4000)
        libmyteams.so => not found
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007414e0bf3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007414e0e1d000)
```

Here is the **Makefile**, I know that it finds the library because it doesn't compile when I intentionally misspell the library name:

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -L../libs/myteams -lmyteams
NAME    = myteams_cli

SRC =   src/main.c  \

OBJ_DIR = obj
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):    $(OBJ)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    gcc -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/src

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

Also, the binary must be executable as soon as the project is compiled. I can't just add the library path to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable every time I want to launch the program (which works, by the way), nor copy the library to `/usr/lib`, because that would require triggering the **Makefile** with `sudo`.

Comment: What is the library _filename_ (e.g. `../libs/myteams`, `../libs/myteams.so`, `../libs/myteams/libmyteams.so`)?

Comment: You may need `-rpath` instead of (or in conjunction with) `-L`

Answer (score 3):

The `-L` option to the linker sets the *link-time search path*.  That is only in effect when linking the program, it doesn't change the *runtime search path* which is where the runtime linker looks for libraries when it starts your program.  As mentioned in the comments, for that you want to use the linker option `-rpath`.  Most compilers don't know that option so you have to pass it through with (for GCC and clang) `-Wl,-rpath`.

If you search the net for "setting runtime search path" and/or "rpath" you'll find much useful info.

In your makefile, you really need to make a distinction between *linker* options and *compiler* options; it's not good to put them all into the same variable like `CFLAGS`.  `CFLAGS` is (by convention) for compiler flags.  You should use `LDFLAGS` for linker flags, and `LDLIBS` for libraries to link (by convention).  So try something like:

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS = -L../libs/myteams -Wl,-rpath=../libs/myteams
LDLIBS = -lmyteams

  ...

$(NAME):    $(OBJ)
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        gcc -o $(NAME) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LDLIBS)
```

(usually we pass compiler flags to the linker as well, just in case)